# Add the same event listener to all buttons with for .. of loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, event-listener, htmlcollection

I am having trouble with adding an event listener to each button of the document, using a `for ... of` loop.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (b of buttons) {
  b.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var n = document.createElement("span");
    n.innerHTML = "new";
    b.parentElement.appendChild(n);
    b.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <dl>
      <dt>Title</dt>
      <dd>Description</dd>
      <dt>Title</dt>
      <dd><button>add content</button></dd>
      <dt>Title</dt>
      <dd>Description</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
      <dt>Title</dt>
      <dd>Description</dd>
      <dt>Title</dt>
      <dd><button>add content</button></dd>
      <dt>Title</dt>
      <dd>Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

The above example only results in the appendig of `n` after the last `button`, not the first. Why is that and how can it be fixed? Is a `for .. of` loop even the right way to do this?

Comment: `for (let b of buttons)`

Comment: thank you, i feel a bit dumb now :D

Comment: No problem, JS is quite lenient in certain cases with its syntax but that can also bite you in the behind :)

Comment: *nitpicker mode* ... does the OP mean ***the same*** or rather ***the selfsame*** or ***the very same***. For the latter case(s) the OP then needs to provide the event listener as a single reference (maybe a function declaration) and not always another fully implemented anonymous callback function.

Comment: In case the OP does utilize [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) the OP then can access a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) which iterates over the returned [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) ... `document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach( /* ... */ );`

Comment: @AbgrundLemur ... From all the comments/answers/approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @AbgrundLemur ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

From both of the above comments ...

> *"**nitpicker mode** ... does the OP mean **the same** or rather **the selfsame** or **the very same**. For the latter case(s) the OP then needs to provide the event listener as a single reference (maybe a function declaration) and not always another fully implemented anonymous callback function."*

> *"In case the OP does utilize [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) the OP then can access a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) which iterates over the returned [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) ... `document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(/* ... */);`"*

And in addition to the already said, the OP might retrieve the currently click button as [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) of the provided [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object.

```js
function handleContentCreation(evt) {
  const button = evt.currentTarget;

  const content = document.createElement('span');
  content.textContent = 'new';

  button.parentElement.appendChild(content);
  button.style.display = 'none';
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('button')
  .forEach(elmNode =>
    elmNode.addEventListener('click', handleContentCreation)
  );
```

```css
:not(dd) { margin: 0!important; padding: 0!important }
body { zoom: .9; }
h1 { font-size: 1.2em; }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <dl>
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd><button>add content</button></dd>
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd><button>add content</button></dd>
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
  </dl>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the 'for' in that way doesn't work. You should use it like this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  b[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var n = document.createElement("span");
    n.innerHTML = "new";
    b[i].parentElement.appendChild(n);
    b[i].style.display = "none";
  });
}
```